# Tool for render dynamic page to create HTMLs

Tags: html, screen-scraping

I am looking for a tool (open source) that will crawl all my page to create a "render" of it.
This is to save resources (database access).

Comment: What do you mean by "render"? To pdf? Image? What platform? You are asking for a tool, so I am assuming this is not a programming question - as such it should be asked on SuperUser.com (where it will probably be shortly migrated to).

Comment: If you're trying to save database resources, wouldn't a simple caching mechanism suffice rather than trying to create a complete rendering of the complete page?

Comment: I think what he wants is to change dynamic pages in to static pages.

Comment: last comment is the right one. Implement a cache will need more costly at the hosting side. Using HTML, will be more cheap I think!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem was this script

http://www.isnull.com.ar/2010/12/tutorial-static-html-generation-with.html